# Nth(n,split()) in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running the following query and keep getting the error message:

```
SELECT NTH(2,split(Web_Address_,'.')) +'.'+NTH(3,split(Web_Address_,'.')) as D , Web_Address_
FROM [Domains.domain 
limit 10
```

> Error message:
>  Error: (L1:110): (L1:119): SELECT clause has mix of
>   aggregations 'D' and 
> fields 'Web_Address_' without GROUP BY
>   clause
>  Job ID:
>   symmetric-aura-572:job_axsxEyfYpXbe2gpmlYzH6bKGdtI

I tried to use `group by clause on field D` and/or `Web_address_`, but still getting errors about `group by`.

Does anyone know why this is the case? I have had success with similar query before.

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo. forgot a ']'. The query is   SELECT NTH(2,split(Web_Address_,'.')) +'.'+NTH(3,split(Web_Address_,'.')) as D , Web_Address_ FROM [Domains.domain] limit 10

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [WITHIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#within) RECORD aggregation here, not GROUP BY

```
    select concat(p1, '.', p2), Web_Address_ FROM 
(SELECT 
  NTH(2,split(Web_Ad`enter code here`dress_,'.')) WITHIN RECORD p1,
  NTH(3,split(Web_Address_,'.')) WITHIN RECORD p2, Web_Address_ 
FROM (SELECT 'a.b.c' as Web_Address_))
```

P.S. If you just trying to cut off first part of web address, it will be easier to do with RIGHT and INSTR functions.

Comment: This works! Thank you very much! I want to take the second and third parts of a string after it is split by '.'. I haven't used within record that often. Will take a look.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using [URL functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#urlfunctions): HOST, DOMAIN and TLD